# Not working hover

Tags: css, hover

I have no clue why this hover doesnt work, there's no negative z-index or something like this. At best case its flashing on hover;

```
.menu{
border-radius: 50%;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: white;
box-shadow:0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
background-image: url("home.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 60% 60%;
background-position: 20px 15px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}
.menucontent{
    height:100px;
    width: 400px;
    box-shadow:0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    position: absolute;
    display:none;
}
.menu:hover .menucontent{
  display: inline;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jwwhj9rr/1/

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

You can do it like this

```
.menu:hover ~.menucontent {
  display: inline;
}
```

Snippet below

```css
.menu {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  background-image: url("home.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 60% 60%;
  background-position: 20px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menucontent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.menu:hover ~.menucontent {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" style="left: 100px; top: 100px; ;"></div>
<div class="menucontent" style="left: 150px; top:100px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.menucontent` is a sibling to `.menu` and hence should be selected using a sibling selector like `~` or `+` like

```
.menu:hover + .menucontent {
  display: inline;
}
```

```css
.menu {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  background-image: url("home.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 60% 60%;
  background-position: 20px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menucontent {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.menu:hover + .menucontent {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" style="left: 100px; top: 100px; ;"></div>
<div class="menucontent" style="left: 150px; top:100px;"></div>
```